# get length of array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection

So I got this class:

```
    public class MyClass{
        public int[] myArray = new int[9];
    }
```

Can I, without the need of initializing an instance of MyClass, get the length of the array?

Comment: no, as this is no static property of the type, rather an instance property - an instance is mandatory!

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need to know that?

Comment: If you need to have some compile-time information alongside something, attributes are the way to go.

Comment: But there is a way to do it. Every initialization like this gets placed into the constructor code before any other code that is explicitly written in constructor is written. What you can do is get the length of array by using reflection and looking through constructor instruction set.

Comment: @Spo1ler that _is_ a possibility, but for the average problem it is not the solution (that is: you most certainly don't want this). OP most likely is solving an XY problem here, where Y is "So I need to get the array length using reflection without instantiating the class". OP forgot to mention problem X.

Comment: I've provided an answer below for the most unrealistic scenario, where OP is dying to know exact size of the array without actually instantiating this class.

Answer (score 8):

> without the need of initializing an instance of MyClass

No. The `= new int[9]` is moved to the constructor, which only runs if you instantiate the class.

Comment: So with an instance you could get it in this way: `((Array)typeof(MyClass).GetField("myArray").GetValue(new MyClass())).Length`

Comment: Yeah, or just `new MyClass().myArray.Length`... not sure what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Selman22: `((Array)typeof(MyClass2).GetField("myArray", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(new MyClass2())).Length;` Try to do that with `new MyClass().myArray.Length` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static readonly int arrayLength = 9;
    public int[] myArray = new int[MyClass.arrayLength];
}
```

Then:

```
MyClass.arrayLength
```

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the IL code of the constructor...

```
var constructor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
var body = constructor.GetMethodBody();
byte[] il = body.GetILAsByteArray();
```

Here you got the IL code... Then you need an IL parser, then you should obtain something like:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: newarr [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: stfld int32[] ExpressionProblem.MyClass::MyArray
IL_000c: ldarg.0
```

then you begin backtraking from the `int32[] ExpressionProblem.MyClass::MyArray`

Hey... I haven't told you this is a *practical* solution. This is a *possible* solution.

Ok... I've prepared a working example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Supports only direct array sizing with values 0...int.MaxValue .
/// Doesn't support: values greater than int.MaxValue, static values,
/// function calling, ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type"></param>
/// <param name="arrayName"></param>
/// <param name="instance"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetSize(Type type, string arrayName, bool instance)
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = (instance ? BindingFlags.Instance : BindingFlags.Static) | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    // The array
    FieldInfo arrayField = type.GetField(arrayName, bindingFlags);

    // We don't know which constructor does the initialization, so we 
    // check each one. We start with the first one, and then we will 
    // follow the chain of constructors
    ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructors(bindingFlags).FirstOrDefault();

    while (constructor != null)
    {
        ConstructorInfo nextConstructor = null;

        var instructions = Mono.Reflection.Disassembler.GetInstructions(constructor);

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < instructions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (instructions[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Call)
            {
                nextConstructor = instructions[i].Operand as ConstructorInfo;

                // If there is a call to another constructor, then 
                // this isn't the method we are looking for :-)
                if (nextConstructor != null)
                {
                    if (constructor.DeclaringType != nextConstructor.DeclaringType)
                    {
                        // Going to base class constructor without 
                        // initializing the field we are interested 
                        // in. We can stop looking.
                        nextConstructor = null;
                    }

                    i = instructions.Count;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // We look for a Stfld operation on the array
            if (instructions[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Stfld && (instructions[i].Operand as FieldInfo) == arrayField)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Access to the array wasn't found. Let's look at the next 
        // constructor
        if (i == instructions.Count)
        {
            constructor = nextConstructor;
            continue;
        }

        // There are too few instructions before this array access
        if (i - 2 < 0)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        OpCode newArr = instructions[i - 1].OpCode;

        // Is the previous instruction a NewArr?
        if (newArr != OpCodes.Newarr)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        var sizeInstruction = instructions[i - 2];

        // Calc the size. There are various opcodes for this.
        int size;

        if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4)
        {
            size = (int)sizeInstruction.Operand;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
        {
            size = 0;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1)
        {
            size = 1;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2)
        {
            size = 2;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3)
        {
            size = 3;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4)
        {
            size = 4;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5)
        {
            size = 5;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6)
        {
            size = 6;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7)
        {
            size = 7;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8)
        {
            size = 8;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1)
        {
            size = -1;
        }
        else if (sizeInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S)
        {
            size = (sbyte)sizeInstruction.Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            // The size of the array was calculated in some other 
            // way. Not supported :-(
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        return size;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

It uses [Mono.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection/). Note that it will work only for simple cases where the array is sized with a constant value. No function calls to initialize it, no reference to other fields to initialize it. Nothing.

Call it like:

```
int size = GetSize(typeof(MyClass), "MyArray", true /* false for static fields */);
```

Note that I **don't** think this is a good idea, unless you **really** need it :)

Comment: Well, your answer is certainly more detailed then mine, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Without either creating an instance or making the member static, it is not possible.

FieldInfo (by reflection) will provide you the fact that it's a int32[] but that's far as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is constant (as it looks like from your example, since it doesn't seem to use any value provided as a parameter in a constructor), you can make the length a constant field and access it at any time, since constants are implicitly static.

Alternatively, as someone said in the comments, marking your class with an attribute that provides this information without introducing new members is also a valid idiomatic way of achieving this.

On the other hand, if the length is not constant but your scenario is still sufficiently simple, you can use a library like Mono Cecil, reflect on the assembly, find this particular type and its constructor, inspect the constructor's IL and infer the value it would have put on the stack if it ran. It's entirely possible, but a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you could instantiate not using 'MyClass'.
And then get the value of the array.

Create an Interface IMyClass and instantiate the class using Activator, like this:

```
var _type = typeof(IMyClass);

var _types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(_s => _s.GetTypes()).Where(_p => _type.IsAssignableFrom(_p) && !_p.IsInterface);

foreach (var _instance in _types)
{
    var _instance = (IMyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(_instance));
    _instance.myArray.Length; 
}
```

Comment: You do undestand, that you are still creating an instance of a class, whether you do it using `Activator` or just `new`ing it?

Comment: Yes I understand, therefore I said '..but you could instantiate not using 'MyClass'..'. In the pre-edited question there stood something like reflection. Thats why I covered that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a sort of way to do it. Look here at the assembly code

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void  .ctor() cil managed
// SIG: 20 00 01
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  /* 1F   | 09               */ ldc.i4.s   9
  IL_0003:  /* 8D   | (01)000013       */ newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0008:  /* 7D   | (04)000001       */ stfld      int32[] ConsoleApplication2.MyClass::myArray
  IL_000d:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
  IL_000e:  /* 28   | (0A)000011       */ call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0013:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_0014:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
```

} // end of method MyClass::.ctor

We are interested in these two instructions

```
ldc.i4.s   9
newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
```

Then using reflection, we can get `MethodBody` for a constructor, from which we can get IL bytes. The problem is that reflection does not actually let you look at existing IL from the standpoint of the IL, but only emit it. But, we know what the bytes are for the instructions we need, so.

ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructors().First();

```
byte[] constructorBytes = constructor.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

int length = constructorBytes[Array.FindIndex(constructorBytes, b => b == 0x1F) + 1];
```

The problem with this code, is that for different numbers it will be different `ldc.i4`, so it will only work if length is between 9 and 256.

I understand, of course, that this will only work for this exact code, but with some modifications and checks there is a way to make it work for almost any class knowing the name of array.

Also, I understand that there is zero reason to do it, but everyone here was telling that this is impossible, which wasn't *quite right*.